# Rendering issue in TeXworks

Tags: texworks, rendering

I use TeXworks 0.6.7 packaged with MiKTeX 23.9.24 to prepare TeX documents, and somehow all of a sudden the application's rendering has notably deteriorated: now every graph has some weird hatch pattern drawn with it (please see the screenshot attached). This must be to do with rendering, as the file looks all right in, for instance, Adobe Reader.

[image: Screenshot]

Have you ever encountered rendering artefacts like this? Could you point me to removing them, please?

Comment: Might it have something to do with Preferences > Preview > Screen Resolution ?

Comment: @rallg, hmmm, I have checked, and it shows 129.91 dpi (which, I think, is the default).

Comment: I can't test with Windows, but my impression is that this is a nuisance when prevewwing your document. On the other hand, you're using TeXworks neither for printing (it can't do it, at least on the platforms I know) nor for displaying the presentation.

Comment: Yes, @egreg, but it started all of a sudden just a couple of hours ago, and sometimes entire vertical lines are invisible. Thinking about that, it appears that the TeXworks renderer adds tiny white lines to everything drawn in tikz/pgfplots somehow.

Comment: Just went for the nuclear option of reinstalling MiKTeX afresh, but the issue still persists somehow.

Comment: And curiously enough, that kind of hatch-line pattern emerges around those little circles at the top too.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, replacing miktex-texworks.exe with the freshest binary (0.6.8) from Github has resolved the issue.
The problem is solved, but the mystery remains...

Comment: I'm encountering a similar problem, but I'm struggling to locate this file on GitHub. Could you provide a link to the file and give a brief explanation of the steps involved in replacing it?