# Ugly Rendering of the output visualization of TeXworks

Tags: texworks

Why having a recent version of `MikTeX` + `TeXworks` is there yet a bad output? The pdf output is perfect.

[image]

Related [Rendering issue in TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697539/rendering-issue-in-texworks)

> What solution exists and what can I do?

**Follow up: 2024/01/30.**

I have just noticed that the issue with TeXworks, as shown in the figure, still persists even after installing the updates from January 27, 2024. I am seeking your assistance. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$y$}; 
    \draw[blue, thick, domain=-2.5:2.5, samples=100] plot (\x, {\x^2});
    \node[blue, above right] at (2.5, 6) {$y = x^2$};
  \draw[red, thick, domain=-2.5:2.5, samples=100] plot (\x, {-\x^2});
  \node[red, below right] at (2.5, -6) {$y = -x^2$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Two Parabolas: $y = x^2$ and $y = -x^2$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably want to say which platform you're on and the code which produces the output. Or do you see the same problem even with a simple 'Hello world!'?

Comment: @cfr The problem is only on the figures.

Comment: In the question three months ago the problem was solved by installing the most recent build from github. This is possibly a bug in the software?

Comment: @EladDen What software? what can I do?

Comment: I have had similar issues, especially notable with lines in `tabular`s.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi dear Steven. What is the solution? :-)

Comment: So far, I have temporarily solved the problem by removing my glasses.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You are fantastic. ahaahahaah

Comment: See my comments at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701022/pdf-quality-issue-in-texworks-preview?noredirect=1&lq=1 for a solution. Just download latest version from github. I provide a link there.

Comment: @yannisl Grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano  di niente!  Drove me mad for days!

Comment: @yannisl Hence I must installed the old TeXworks. But somebody can do a report on the bug of TeXworks for MikTeX?

Comment: Here there is my advice on github: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1435

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by updating with new MikTeX+Texworks.

Comment: @yannisl The problem yet persist. I ask the open of the question. Thank you very much.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The problem yet persist: see my edit. Ciaooooooooooooooooo.

Comment: @cfr The problem yet exist. ;.(

Comment: @Sebastiano` C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\TeXworks-win10-0.6.8-202302181302-git_6b1c6ab`  I left it in the Downloads folder and then created a shortcut to the Start Menu. This worked well since and I have been updating packages regularly. Also voted to reopen the question.

Comment: It might help if you provided an MWE, so others could check the same piece of code.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I must have a bit of the time. Unfortunately, I do not enjoy good health these days.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Dear Steven I have provide to put an MWE.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear of your poor health. I pray for your full restoration.

Comment: And, yes, I can recreate the irregular result, in which the solid lines of the graph appear dashed when viewing in TeXworks viewer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Trank you very much for your support and encouragment.

Comment: Interestingly, when I tried to update packages last evening, MikTeX Console produced an error, which caused MikTeX to become inoperable.  When I tried to reinstall MikTeX, it told me I needed Windows 10 (I'm still on 8.1).  As a result, I converted over to TeXLive, which still works on my system.  Lo and behold, it also uses TeXWorks editor, which was great.  And the editor viewer produced crisp and clear renderings.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi Steven. It is true that with TeXlive, the rendering of TeXworks works correctly. The problem is on MikTeX. I have done a issue for MikTeX/TeXworks: https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/1037. My best regards.